# Horizontal UITableView - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

How can I create a `horizontally UITableView`?

I don't like to use library.

Comment: Use UICollectionView and disable vertical scrolling instead. It has built in support for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @  Shreeram Bhat. I can't use from uitableview?

Comment: No. TableView is not meant for that.

Comment: @ Shreeram Bhat. Ok thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView is not meant to be used for horizontal scrolling. A Table View's core function is to display vertically scrolling content with sections and rows. If horizontal scrolling is what you need, please look into [UICollectionViews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview).